# Adding attachments using url in mail with C sharp

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, csharpcodeprovider

I can send attachments with URLs, But, looking for support to send a file with an attachment. that too should download from url and attach with mail.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@email.com");

//to mail address
mail.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);

//Add the Attachment
mail.Attachments.Add(data);

//set the content 
mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
mail.Body = "Kindly find the below attachments with the link, https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo@2x.png";

//send the message 
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("*****.********.net");

NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@email.com", "********");
smtp.Credentials = Credentials;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Here I'm sending mail with URL as a file,
**But I want to attach a file instead of sending a link**

The sample URL was added as an image link.. But I wanted to add a pdf link..
In this case, I want to download a file and attach it with mail,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine and mail directly reaches inbox instead of spam.. also can able to attach files from serverpath. Thank you everyone who wish to answer my questions..

```
    {
        try
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("tomail@gmail.com");
            
            //set the content 
            string filename = "Report1";

            string fileurl = Server.MapPath("..");
            fileurl = fileurl + @"\mailserver\pdf\generated\" + filename + ".pdf";


            //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileurl));
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileurl))
            {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileurl, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
                ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
                disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(fileurl);
                disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileurl);
                disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(fileurl);
                disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileurl);
                disposition.Size = new FileInfo(fileurl).Length;
                disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            mail.Subject = "Subject Text";
            mail.Body = "Body Text";

            //send the message 
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpout.****.******server.net");

            NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "Password@123");
            smtp.Credentials = Credentials;
            
            //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            
            Response.Write("<center><span style='color:green'><b>Mail has been send successfully!</b></span></center>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write("<center><span style='color:red'><b>"+ ex + "</b></span></center>");

            Response.Write("<center><span style='color:red'><b>Failed to send a mail...Please check your mail id or Attachment missing</b></span></center>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use it mostly in my all projects it's working fine. its with base 64

First, make sure your Gmail account is turned on for sending emails.

```
    public static async Task SendEmail(string toUser, string subject, string body
        , string username, string password, string port, string smtpServer, string ccUsers = "", string base64Url = "")
    {
        var toAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(toUser, toUser);


        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage emessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

        emessage.To.Add(toAddress);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccUsers))
        {
            string[] ccIds = ccUsers.Split(',');
            foreach (string item in ccIds)
            {
                emessage.CC.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(item));
            }
        }

        emessage.Subject = subject;
        emessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(username);
        emessage.Body = body;
        emessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient sc = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64Url))
        {
            base64Url = base64Url.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
            var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Url);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
            System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment at = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, ct);
            at.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Invoice.jpeg";
            emessage.Attachments.Add(at);
        }


        var netCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        sc.Host = smtpServer;
        sc.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        sc.Credentials = netCredential;
        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Port = Convert.ToInt32(port);
        await sc.SendMailAsync(emessage);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. Can you suggest with the matter of PDF?

Comment: Hi Davinder Singh, I tried the same but mail sending to recipient's spam box instead of inbox. Anyways it working fine..

Comment: Please check the other answers, I updated the matter of PDF..